# Which cucumberautocomplete settings should I use to replace a {string} with "" double-quotes when autocompleting a step? Not ("|')[^\1]*\1 or ("|')\1

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, cucumber, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am building a `Cypress` Framework using the `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` node package and the `Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support` vs code extension.

**When autocompleting a step that contains {string} I would like to replace {string} with "" instead of ("|')[^\1]*\1  or ("|')\1**

My `.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "json": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "stepDefinitions": "**/*.steps.js"
}
```

My `settings.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "explorer.sortOrder": "filesFirst",
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": "**/*.steps.js",
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "**/features/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.skipDocStringsFormat": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.onTypeFormat": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": false,
        "strings": true,
        "other": true
    },
    "cucumberautocomplete.gherkinDefinitionPart": "(Given|When|Then)\\("
}
```

For example, I have a step definition as follows:

```
When("I click the {string}", (element) => {
    //some code
});
```

With the above settings and `smartSnippets` set to `true` I get the following autocompleted step:

```
When I click the ("|')\1
```

With the above settings but changing `smartSnippets` to `false` I get the following autocompleted step:

```
When I click the ("|')[^\1]*\1
```

What I would like to get is this autocompleted step:

```
When I click the ""
```

Comment: [UPDATE] A PR has been created to resolve this issue here:
https://github.com/alexkrechik/VSCucumberAutoComplete/pull/474

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to install Regexp Explain extension.

Then modify your settings.json file the following way:

```
{
  "explorer.sortOrder": "filesFirst",
  "cucumberautocomplete.steps": "**/*.steps.js",
  "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "**/features/*.feature",
  "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.skipDocStringsFormat": true,
  "cucumberautocomplete.onTypeFormat": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true,
    "other": true
  },
  "cucumberautocomplete.gherkinDefinitionPart": "(Given|When|Then)\\(",
  "regexp-explain.expressions": {
    "cypress-step-parameter": {
      "expression": "\"(.*?)\"",
      "prefix": "",
      "suffix": ""
    }
  },
  "cucumberautocomplete.gherkinRegEx": "cypress-step-parameter"
}
```

With this setup once you start entering `{string}` in single quotes the extension is going to replace it with double quotes.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have installed the Regexp Explain extension and updated my settings.json file.

However, the properties "regexp-explain.expressions" and "cucumberautocomplete.gherkinRegEx" could not be found, and so, the issue still  persists.

Is there some other configuration required?